# What is a good regex to match a word with optional space in it?

Tags: regex

Digits are optional, and are only allowed in the end of a word

Spaces are optional, and are only allowed in the middle of a word.

I am pretty much just trying to match the possible months in a few languages, say English and Vietnamese

For example, the following are valid matches:

`'June'`
`'tháng 6'`

But the following are not because of space: `'June '` `' June'`

This is my testcases: https://regex101.com/r/pZ0mN3/2.

As you can see, I came up with `^\S[\S ]+\S$` which is kind of working, but I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean with *middle of a word*, the real middle (one index), or simply that there should be text before and behind?

Comment: Include relevant "code" and sample data **in the question itself**.

Comment: If you need to match 1 char strings, use [`^(?=\S)(?=.*\S$)[\S ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/pZ0mN3/3).

Comment: I like the solution @WiktorStribiżew gave. You could also use a `|`: `^(\S+[\S ]*\S|\S+)+$`, this would account for 1-character-long strings, too.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, as long as space doesn't appear in the beginning or end of the word, it is fine.

Comment: @VladislavMartin: I guess you meant to write `^(\S+[\S ]*\S|\S)+$`. Otherwise, backtracking is overshooting!

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Ah yes, I pressed the '+' key too many times. Thank you for correcting it

Answer (score 2):

To match a string with no leading and trailing spaces in the JavaScript regex flavor, you can use several options:

- Require the first and the last non-whitespace character with `\S` (=`[^\s]`). This can be done with, say, `^\S[\S\s]*\S$`. **This regex requires at least 2 characters to be in the string**. Your regex requires 3 chars in the input since you used `+`. It won't allow some Unicode whitespaces either.
- You may use a combination of grouping with optional quantifiers (those allowing 0 length matches). See [`^\S(?:\s*\S+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/vO8uE8/1) (where `\s` is replaced with   since it is a multiline demo). The `\S` at the beginning matches a non-whitespace char and then a non-capturing group follows, that is `*` quantified (matches zero or more occurrences) and matches 0+ sequences of 0+ whitespaces followed with 1+ non-whitespace characters. **This is a good expression for those flavors like RE2 that do not support lookarounds, but support quantified groups.**
- You may use lookaheads to require the first and last character to be non-whitespace characters: `^(?=[\S\s]*\S$)\S[\S\s]*$` where `(?=[\s\S]*\S$)` requires the last char to be a non-whitespace and the `\S` after the lookahead will require the first char to be non-whitespace. `[\s\S]*` matches 0+ any characters. **This will match 1 char strings, but won't match empty strings**.
- If your regex to match strings with no leading/trailing whitespaces should also **match an empty string**, use 2 negative lookaheads: [`^(?!\s)(?![\S\s]*\s$)[\S\s]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/tG2hE4/1). The `(?!\s)` lookahead will fail the match if there is a leading whitespace, `(?![\S\s]*\s$)` will do the same in case of trailing whitespace, and `[\s\S]*` will match 0+ any characters. *If lookarounds are not supported, use `^(?:\S(?: *\S+)*)?$` that is much less efficient.

If you do not need to match any chars between the non-whitespace chars, you may revert `[\s\S]` to your `[\S ]`. In PCRE, a horizontal whitespace can be matched with `\h`, in .NET and others that support Unicode properties, you can use `[\t\p{Zs}]` to match any horizontal whitespace. In JS, `[^\S\r\n\f\v\u2028\u2029]` can be used for that purpose.

**Note** that some regex flavors do not support non-capturing groups, you may replace all `(?:` with `(` in the above patterns.